# Joining polars dataframes while ignoring duplicate values in the on column

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

Given the code

```
df1 = pl.DataFrame({"A": [1, 1], "B": [3, 4]})
df2 = pl.DataFrame({"A": [1, 1], "C": [5, 6]})
result = df1.join(df2, on='A')
```

`result` looks like

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 5   │
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 6   │
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

but I would like it to be

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 5   │
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Experimenting with `left_on`, `right_on` and `how` parameters did not resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tables are aligned (possibly, after sorting by the *on* column), you can concatenate them horizontally using [`pl.concat`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat.html).

```py
pl.concat([df1.sort("A"), df2.sort("A").drop("A")], how="horizontal")
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 5   │
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

If one table contains more rows and you want to keep the extra rows, you could add an extra column to store the index of the row among all  rows with same *on* column(s). Then, you can join the tables using both *on* column(s) and the index.

```
(
    df1
    .with_columns(pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("A").alias("id"))
    .join(
        df2.with_columns(pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("A").alias("id")),
        on=["A", "id"],
        how="left",
    )
    .select(pl.exclude("id"))
)
```

Comment: you could also use [`with_row_index`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.with_row_index.html) to add an index

Comment: @RomanPekar Is there a way to apply it over groups?

Comment: I don't believe so. You can put the expr into the `on=` e.g. `df1.join(df2, on=["A", pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("A")], how="left")` - but you can't use `.alias` in there so it requires the expression itself produces a distinct name (in this case int_range gives the name `literal` so it works)

Comment: @jqurious Hmm.. This gives me `ComputeError: the length of the window expression did not match that of the group`.

Comment: Ah interesting. It works for me with the example frames but perhaps that's because there are only 2 matching rows in both. I guess using expressions directly in `on=` still has issues and probably not as useful as I initially thought.